# Can I reference a named URL in an included URLConf using Django's "url" tag?

Tags: django

In my Django project, I used to have a single URLConf, `urls.py` at the root of the project. This URLConf included some named URLs using Django's `url()` function. In several templates, I reference these URLs with the `url` tag, à la `{% url named_url %}`. This worked fine.

The root `urls.py` became a bit unwieldy, so I split it off into a URLConf for each app, in `app/urls.py`. Some URLs still have names. Unfortunately, I get a `TemplateSyntaxException` when using the `url` tag in templates now. Specifically, the error message is:

> Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'myproj.myapp.new_test' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Is there a way to reference the named URLs in the app-specific URLConfs using the `url` tag in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can reference urls in included urlconfs via the `url` tag - that's in fact what you're supposed to do. However, I've always found the `url` tag and the `reverse()` function to be very flaky and error-prone, so these errors do sometimes occur.

My suggestion would be to give *all* your urls a name, no matter which urlconf they are in. Then you just need to refer to the actual name - you don't need to qualify it with the name of the app or urlconf or anything. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing each app's urls.py?

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^app1/',        include('app1.urls')),
    (r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
)
```

from [Django Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Comment: Yes. The URLs themselves work fine (as in, I can navigate to them without getting a 404). It's just the use of {% url %} that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not useful to you but hopefully useful to the next bloke searching for an answer:

I am using Django 1.4 and what solved it for me was not using quotes in the template tag:

```
{% url 'name_of_view' some_var %}
```

became this:

```
{% url name_of_view some_var %}
```

And that cured it. I didn't see any mention of this in the django docs and the examples in the docs use quotes. So this seems a little buggy but hopefully will keep someone from pulling out their hair.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend you two things:

- [Use name in url patterns](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2)
- Do not do references to the project name inside a app(like you did with "myproj.myapp.new_test". If this was the "right way to do", you should only reference as "myapp.new_test"

Comment: I _am_ using names in URL patterns, as I noted in the question. And I'm _not_ "doing references to the project name", but Django gives the full view path (including the project name) in its error message.

Comment: Sorry. I read that, but I thought otherwise because of the error.